# Bash: converting a string with both spaces and quotes to an array

Tags: bash, shell-script, bash-array

I have a function (not created by me) that outputs a series of strings inside of quotes:

```
command <args>

“Foo”
“FooBar”
“Foo Bar”
“FooBar/Foo Bar”
```

When I try to assign it to an array (Bash; BSD/Mac), instead of 4 elements, I get 7.  For example, for `${array[2]}` I *should* get `“Foo Bar”`, but instead, I get `”Foo` with the next element being `Bar”`.  Any element *without* the space works correctly (i.e. `${array[0]}` = “Foo”)

**How can assign each of these elements between the quote including the space to an array that the elements are  separated by spaces(?) themselves?**

Right now, I am thinking of using sed/awk to “strip” out the quotes, but I think there should be a better and more efficient way.

Currently, I am assigning the output of the command (looks exactly like the output above including the quotes) to a temporary variable then assigning it to an array.

```
_tempvar=“$(command <args>)”

declare -a _array=(${_tempvar})
```

Comment: Are those really `U+201C LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` and `U+201D RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK` quote characters like in your question or are they in reality the simple ASCII U+0022 QUOTATION MARK?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - What I typed were the simple quotation marks, but to be completely accurate as to what gets output, I’ll have to get back to you on that (on an iPad at the moment and can’t check.)

Comment: are those quoted strings one per line? Because that would mean you could just focus on the lines, and not the quotes. Which is much simpler.

Comment: If you complain that your array assignment does not work as expected then you really should show to us how you did the assignment.

Comment: @HaukeLaging, see edit at bottom

Comment: those 'style quotes' are the default behaviour on ios devices, there's an option to change them to normal, I used to have the same issue. Since op typed this on ipad its likely the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get 7 elements because word splitting is occuring, caused by the spaces.

Set `IFS=$'\n'` before adding the strings to the array then you'll get 4 elements but with double quotes.

Example:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

arr=($(command <args>))
```

If you want 4 elements without quotes do this:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

arr=($(command <args> | sed s'#"##'g))
```

Full example:

```bash
IFS=$'\n'

# tst.txt has your strings:
arr=($(cat tst.txt | sed s'#"##'g))

declare -p arr
```

Output:

```bash
declare -a arr=([0]="Foo" [1]="FooBar" [2]="Foo Bar" [3]="FooBar/Foo Bar")
```

Comment: Setting `$IFS` is not enough. You also need to disable globbing if you're to use split+glob. See my answer

Comment: He wanted 4 elements right? Or what did I miss? check my array output

Comment: curious on why you need to disable globbing, is it because on array creation op uses a variable instead of directly using the cmd?

Comment: globbing is done upon unquoted expansions in shells such as bash. See for instance: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) (see the *What about when you do need the split+glob operator?* section there in particular). Here for instance, try with a command that outputs `"/*/*/"`

Comment: alright I see, but couldn't the whole glowing problem be avoided by not doing this ```_tempvar=“$(command <args>)”

declare -a _array=(${_tempvar})``` and instead just doing ```declare -a _array=("$(command <args>)")``` setting the variable like that seems redundant since it's used once.

Comment: I appreciate an answer that is direct, to the point and doesn’t go off tangent in to “better” or “different” shells.  I am on both macOS (some older than Catalina) and FreeBSD and switching shells or installing new ones isn’t an option - therefore I like to keep things simple.

Comment: thanks, I noticed you didn't want to use `sed` you could use the bash substitution that @StéphaneChazelas suggested instead, also @alan I set IFS like in the answer in my bash_profile then you don't have to quote anything and I've never had an issue with it, the security implications are actually special cases one example being using bash for api stuff

Comment: the only time you have to worry about quoting when you have IFS set like in the answer is when you have a wildcard like `*` that you want to be interpreted literally, again a special case and  usually if I use `*` I'd want it to expand, perhaps if you're using regexes then you'd want to quote so it gets interpreted literally

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas have you heard of `set noglob`?

Comment: `set noglob` is the csh syntax to disable globbing. In bash it's `set -o noglob` like in any POSIX-like shell as shown in my answer or `set -f` like in the Bourne shell.

Comment: Thank you for correcting yourself @StéphaneChazelas that is very much appreciated, as it was you who have suggested the `set noglob` option on my bash scripts many times when I'd set `IFS` to my most suited value. Nice to see you bowed your head down and corrected your erroneous information, that is very commendable, takes a real man to do that, especially since this was an error made by you countless times last year.

Answer (score 4):

In `bash`, you'd use `readarray` to read the lines of a file or from the output of some command into an array; however that was *only*  added in version 4.0 released in 2009, but macos still comes with bash 3.2.

macos comes with zsh though which is a much better shell.

To get the non-empty lines of the output of a command you'd split it with the `f` parameter expansion flag (which splits on line`f`eed), and to delete the `"` (U+0022), `“` (U+0201C) and `”` (U+201D) characters, use the `${var//pattern[/replacement]}` operator for instance:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
array=( ${(f)${"$(cmd)"//['"“”']}} ) || exit
```

If those are strings quoted with the U+0022 ASCII character and the quoting is compatible with the way quotes work in the `zsh` language, you can also use its `z`/`Z` flag (to tokenise text the same way as the language parser does) and `Q` flag (to remove quotes) instead of splitting by line (which would assume quoted strings can't span several lines).

```
#! /bin/zsh -
array=( ${(Q)${(Z[n])"$(cmd)"}} ) || exit
```

---

Your

> ```
> declare -a array=(${tempvar})
> ```

in `bash` uses the split+glob operator which is invoked when an expansion is left (usually unintentionally) unquoted. It splits the output on characters of the special `$IFS` parameter (which by default in bash contains space, tab and newline) using a complex algorithm and the resulting words subject to *globbing* aka *filename generation* (which is hardly ever desirable).

Here, split+glob could be used to get you the non-empty lines of the output of your command, but you'd need to tune it first:

```
IFS=$'\n' # split on newline only:
set -o noglob # disable the glob part which we don't want
array=( $(cmd) ) # split+glob
```

Then you can remove the `"“”` with `${var//pattern[/replacement]}` as well but in bash that  has to be done in subsequently as it can't cumulate parameter expansion operators and the syntax (inherited from ksh93) is a bit more awkward:

```
array=( "${array[@]//['"“”']}" )
```

Note that contrary to the `zsh` approach, that won't handle things like `"foo \"bar\" and \\backslash"`.

Answer (score -2):

```
readarray -t array <<< $(echo $'"a a"\n"b   b"\n"c   c"')
declare -p array
declare -a array=([0]="\"a a\"" [1]="\"b   b\"" [2]="\"c   c\"")
```

```
readarray -t array <<< $(command <args>)
```